# Ajax Page with ASP WebForms

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

I'm amateur with asp and .net, but i need create a page to generate xml/json output response similar to java servlet.

what is the best way to do ajax response with asp forms? Asp page form with

```
  ContentType="text/xml;utf-8"
```

????

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is create not page but handler ( ashx file, 'generic handler' item in New item dialog ).

There you get full control over output.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.Write("Hello World");
```

Comment: Brillant! Thanks a lot, Now.. how to i can handle url templates.. example for this 'generic handler' process pattern with all url /test/*

Comment: There are several ways to do that: IIS rewrite http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/ or Url Routing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx